# Autocomplete "select" not centering on map

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, jquery

Everything seems to be working good until I select from the list of names.  The map isn't centering on the proper coordinates.  I'm using JQuery UI and and OpenLayers 3.  here's my code:

```
$(function () {
    function log(message) {
        $("<div/>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
        $("#log").scrollTop(0);
    }
    var centerCoords;
    $("#city").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?username=XXXX",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('.input-group-addon').html("<i class='fa fa-spinner'></i>");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.geonames, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryCode,
                            value: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryCode,
                            lat: item.lat,
                            lng: item.lng
                        };
                    }));
                    $('.input-group-addon').html("<i class='fa fa-search'></i>");
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            log(ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            var location = ol.proj.transform([ui.item.lng, ui.item.lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
            console.log(location);

            var a = map.getView();
            a.setCenter(location);
            a.setZoom(14);

            var marker = new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Point(location)
            });
            var vectorSource3 = new ol.source.Vector({
                features: [marker]
            });
            vectorSource3.addFeature(marker);

            var vectorlayer3 = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: vectorSource3
            });

            var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Icon({
                    anchor: [0.5, 46],
                    opacity: 0.75,
                    scale: 0.10,
                    anchorXUnits: 'fraction', 
                    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                    src: "../images/flag.png"
                })
            });
            marker.setStyle(iconStyle);
            map.addLayer(vectorlayer3);

        },
        open: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
            $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
        },
        close: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

```
var vectorSource3;
   $("#city").keypress(function (e) {
       var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
       if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
          return false;
    }
});

$(function () {
    function log(message) {
        $("<div/>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
        $("#log").scrollTop(0);
    }
    $("#city").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?username=XXXX",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('.input-group-addon').html("<i class='fa fa-spinner'></i>");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.geonames, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryCode,
                            value: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryCode,
                            lat: item.lat,
                            lng: item.lng
                        };
                    }));
                    $('.input-group-addon').html("<i class='fa fa-search'></i>");
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        open: function (event) {
            $(".input-group").css("z-index", 1000);

        },
        close: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
            $("#city").val('');
            $("#city").html('');
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
           map.removeLayer(vectorlayer3);
            log(ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            var lat = parseFloat(ui.item.lat);
            var lng = parseFloat(ui.item.lng);
            var booH = ol.proj.fromLonLat([lng, lat]);
            var a = map.getView();
            a.setCenter(booH);
            a.setZoom(11);
            var flag = new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Point(booH)
            });
            vectorSource3 = new ol.source.Vector({
                features: flag
            });
            var vectorlayer3 = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: vectorSource3,
                style: iconStyle
            });
            var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Icon({
                    anchor: [0.5, 20],
                    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                    opacity: 0.75,
                    src: "../images/geolocation_marker.png"
                })
            });
            flag.setStyle(iconStyle);
            vectorSource3.addFeature(flag);
            map.addLayer(vectorlayer3);
        }
    });
});
```